# Uso incorrecto de UPDATE y ORDER BY

Tags: mysql, sql

tengo este error no puedo actualizar mi tabla,
quiero que use el ultimo registro de **product_id**

```
UPDATE sma_products
       INNER JOIN sma_sale_items
          ON sma_sale_items.product_id = sma_products.id
    SET sma_products.acumulado = sma_sale_items.acumulado
ORDER BY product_id, DESC;
```

Tengo #1221 de error. Sin la cláusula order by, la sentencia funciona bien. ¿Hay alguien que sepa una solución para este problema?

UPDATE: aplicando esta consulta me agrupa por product_id y los acumulados los suma para arrojar el resultado esperado, ahora solo quedará actualizar la tabla sma_products para cada id.

```
select (product_id),(acumulado) from sma_sale_items
GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY product_id DESC
```

https://i.stack.imgur.com/0JBvT.jpg

Comment: ¿Por qué tratas de hacer un ordenamiento?, ¿qué resultado esperas obtener?

Comment: mm quizá no me deje entender, quiero que tome el ultimo registro por que es el que lleva el acumulado final, quitando el ordenamiento lo hace, pero toma el primer registro y no lleva acumulado.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

La sentencia `ORDER BY` va a ordenar los valores que obtengas y no aquellos que actualices necesariamente.

De hecho la sentencia de `UPDATE` solo te debería informar como salida:

- Tiempo estimado que duró la acción
- Número de filas afectadas
- Si es que acaso ocurrió algún error

El ordenamiento estaría solo presente cuando haces una toma de filas de una o varias tablas por medio de la sentencia:

```
SELECT * FROM tu Tabla;
```

Aquí [en la documentación oficial](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/order-by-optimization.html) puedes leer mas al respecto.

Sin embargo dado lo que comentas puede ser que te funcione esto:

- En la parte del `ON` en lugar de hacer directamente la evaluación de llave primaria contra llave foránea
- Metemos en una subconsulta la `SELECCIÓN` del último `product_id`
- Para limitarlo al último podemos hacer un select solo de esa columna, un ordenamiento descendente que nos de el último id y para evitar que nos de un error de que la subconsulta devuelve mas de 1 row hacemos un `LIMIT 1`

Consulta:

```
UPDATE sma_products
INNER JOIN sma_sale_items
ON sma_products.id = (SELECT product_id FROM sma_sale_items ORDER BY product_id DESC LIMIT 1)
SET sma_products.acumulado = sma_sale_items.acumulado;
```

Comment: gracias leyendo la documentación tienes mucha razón, ahora intente probar la consulta y no me arroja ningún resultado, solo 0 columnas afectadas.

Comment: Entonces no da ninguna coincidencia amigo, ayudaría si agregas la declaración de tus tablas y unos datos de prueba

Comment: no he podido actualizar la tabla pero conseguí hacer esta consulta y es lo que quiero, `select (product_id),(acumulado) from sma_sale_items
GROUP BY product_id ORDER BY product_id DESC ` aquí agrupa por product_id y muestra el acumulado de todos.